# iOS approve App Store with login in webview

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, app-store

We are developing a simple iOS native App which has:

> - Splash
> - 3 sections of public company information.
> - Google Cloud Push notifications.
> - Access to a private (login) section which is embedded in a webview (remotely hosted URL).

My question is: Is apple going to approve our App?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly take a Note:

> Login in Webview would not be an issue for rejecting App by Apple.

But the thing you need to take in mind is :

> App with less features & it doesn't have enough features will be rejected by Apple

Hope it will help you.